# Annoying whitespace created by prettier

Tags: html, vue.js, eslint, prettier

I have a Vue/Nuxt app with ESLint and Prettier installed and I recently got a very annoying problem regarding whitespaces. It seems like Prettier reformats my code when using native HTML elements like `p` and it adds extra whitespaces, which I don't want.

Whenever changing my tag to a custom HTML tag like a component, it doesn't happen anymore.

Any idea on how to fix that ?

*Original code*

```html
<Title some="attributes" that="create" a="long" line>{{
  text
}}</Title>
<p class="paragraph">{{
  someMoreText
}}</p>
```

*Formatted code*

```html
<Title some="attributes" that="create" a="long" line>{{
  text
}}</Title>
<p class="paragraph">
  {{ someMoreText }}
</p>
```

It's a bit weird because it works for `Title` but not `p`.

*.eslintrc.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  plugins: [],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    'no-console': 'off',
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': [
      'error',
      {
        ignores: ['default'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

*.prettierrc*

```json
{
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.yml"],
      "options": {
        "singleQuote": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Prettier works the way it works. Make sure that template minification is enabled, this is the way to have consistent result in a working app